# toast cant be displayed

Tags: android, toast

i have toast message which i am displaying in the background thread.

here is what i am trying to display in my `AsyncTask`.

```
ParseDetails Objparsecities = new ParseDetails(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(result.toString()
                .getBytes("UTF-8")));
if ((Objparsecities.parse().size()) == 0) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "No result found for" + params[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

} else
    lstresponse = Objparsecities.parse();
}
```

can i know what's the mistake i am doing.

Thanks:)

Comment: is that simple activity or extending something else

Comment: are you sure your codition is true all the times ? Put Toast in else also and try.

Comment: you cant display it in background thread as far as i know, as it is a UI Element... If you are using asynchtask then display it on onPostExecute...

or try running it on UIThread

Comment: Is this piece of code in doInBackground() of your AsyncTask?

Comment: @AbhinavRathore Thanx:).. i tried in onpostexecute.. it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here is what i am trying to display in my AsyncTask.

AsyncTask provides a few methods which allow user to update UI with specific information. So you can move your Toast into

- onPreExecute()
- onProgressUpdate()
- onPostExecute()

These methods run on Main(UI) Thread and allow update or modify UI.

If you want to show `Toast` with some information during background processing, call publishProgress() in your doInBackground() method which immediately invokes `onProgressUpdate()` method and there you can simply call `Toast.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `runOnUiThread`

```
if ((Objparsecities.parse().size()) == 0) {
  context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(context,
                    "No result found for" + params[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
  }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onPostExecute - executes on UI thread or publishProgress(); in your doinbackground and

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
 }
```

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)